# Each time i tried running this code it give 'unexpected end input error message'''

Tags: jquery

I keep getting unexpected input error on this code

```js
$('.js--wp-4').waypoint(function(direction){
        $('.js--wp-4').addClass('animated pulse');
    },{
        offset:'50%'
    });
```

Comment: What HTML is this being executed on? What is this expected to do?

Comment: give a full code